# How do I import a file from the res folder in adroid studio with kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, import, importerror

I created a recyclerView variable in an xml named `activiy_main.xml` and i want to access it in the MainActivity file
I tried different ways to import the xml file but I get an error each time.
I added a picture of the navigation in the project, what am I missing?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHohC.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your `activiy_main.xml` your recyclerview should look something like

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/my_recyclerview"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                            tools:listitem="@layout/featured_product_item"/>
```

in your activity you can access it like so:

```
val recyclerview = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.my_recyclerview)
```

Comment: yeh, well i know that but i want to add layoutManager to it and i can do it only at the activity page, therfor i need to import the xml file but i dont know how, that was the assent of my question